# Android ORMLite find column as an integer type

Tags: android, ormlite

In ORMLite class database structure I want to find integer value by column name such as this SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE my_id = 1;
```

class structure:

```
public class WaybillStructure {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField
    public static int waybill_id;
}
```

Now I want to find where row in database have `200` by this code :

```
int waybill_id = 200;
List<WaybillStructure> waybillList = G.waybillDao.queryBuilder().where().eq(WaybillStructure.waybill_id , waybill_id + "" ).query();
```

But I get this error :

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'int', required: 'java.lang.String'
```

for `WaybillStructure.waybill_id` section in `queryBuilder`

`waybill_id` column type is `int` and I want to find as an integer in database, how to resolve this problem in ORMLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have placed the arguments for your `eq()` in the incorrectly. The first argument refers to the `String` representation of the column name and the second argument to the value you wish to run the equality test against.

The following should solve your issue:

```
G.waybillDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("waybill_id", waybill_id).query();
```